# Remove a range of elements from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, splice

I want to remove a range of elements from an `array`:

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange1", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Banana", "Orange", "Mango", "Bananax", "Orangex"];
var a = fruits.indexOf("Apple");
var b = fruits.indexOf("Mango");

var removedCars = fruits.splice(a, b);

console.log(fruits);
```

So I am expecting:

```
["Banana", "Orange1", "Bananax", "Orangex"]
```

But the result is:

```
["Banana", "Orange1", "Orangex"]
```

Why is this happening?

Are there any faster and better ways of doing this?

Comment: You are not using the splice function correctly. The first parameter defines number of items, while the second is the start index.

Comment: [`array.splice(start, deleteCount)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) That second parameter isn't an index.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The second param of **[Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)**  is the number of elements to be removed and not an ending index.

You can see from the [**Array.prototype.splice()** MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) that:

> **Parameters**
>
> `start` Index at which to start changing the array (with origin 0). If
> greater than the length of the array, actual starting index will be
> set to the length of the array. If negative, will begin that many
> elements from the end of the array (with origin 1) and will be set to
> 0 if absolute value is greater than the length of the array.
>
> `deleteCount` Optional An integer indicating the number of old array
> elements to remove. If deleteCount is 0, no elements are removed. In
> this case, you should specify at least one new element. If deleteCount
> is greater than the number of elements left in the array starting at
> start, then all of the elements through the end of the array will be
> deleted.

**Solution:**

You need to calculate the number of elements between these two indexes, so use `(b - a) + 1` to get the correct count.

**Demo:**

This is your code with the proper usage of `splice`:

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange1", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Banana", "Orange", "Mango", "Bananax", "Orangex"];
var a = fruits.indexOf("Apple");
var b = fruits.indexOf("Mango");

var removedFruits = fruits.splice(a, (b - a) + 1);

console.log(fruits);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it with filter:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange1", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Banana", "Orange", "Mango", "Bananax", "Orangex"];
var a = fruits.indexOf("Apple");
var b = fruits.indexOf("Mango");

//returns items not equal to a or b
function fruitfilter(item, index){
return index !== a && index !== b;
}

//apply the filter to the array, returns a new array
var newfruits = fruits.filter(fruitfilter);
 //log the new fruits
console.log(newfruits);
```

Here's a jsfiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/a41h0yg0/10/)

Answer (score 0):

That happens because array.splice() take the first index and the number of elements you want to delete not the last index
try that

```
fruits.splice(a, b - a + 1);
```