# Swift, How to remove a range of elements from an array

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, instance

I need to remove a range of elements from an array in Swift.  Here is the javascript version of exactly what I need to do in Swift:
[Remove a range of elements from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46198689/remove-a-range-of-elements-from-an-array)

javascript code: 'array.splice(start, deleteCount)'

I have tried to use the ".removeSubrange" instance but Xcode gives the following warning:

"Variable 'array1Adjusted' inferred to have type '()', which may be unexpected"

Here is my simple code:

```
var array1 = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]

var array1Adjusted = array1.removeSubrange(5..<9)
```

And next I need to find the sum of all the elements of array1Adjusted...

```
var sumArray1Adjusted = array1Adjusted.reduce(0, +)
```

...but I get the following error:

"Value of tuple type '()' has no member 'reduce'"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array1.removeSubrange(5..<9)` *does work*. It just doesn't create a new array that you can assign to `array1Adjusted`. Instead, it modifies `array1` in place.

```
var array1 = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
array1.removeSubrange(5..<9)
print(array1) // [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100]
```

If you don't want to modify `array1`, you can do:

```
let everythingExcept5to9 = array1[...5] + array1[9...]
print(everythingExcept5to9) // [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100]
```

Note that `everythingExcept5to9` is an [`ArraySlice`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/arrayslice), which is a "view" into the original array you sliced it from. The slice would have the old array's indices, so if you want a proper new array, you should do:

```
let newArray = Array(array1[...5] + array1[9...])
```

Comment: Another option is using compactMap `let array1Adjusted = array1.indices.compactMap { 5..<9 ~= $0 ? nil : array1[$0] }`